# cmake find_package full list of installed modules

Tags: cmake

Where, or how, can I get the full list of packages supported by find_package?
I understand those are modules, so they must reside somewhere?
I'm building on online automated packaging system for C++/ROS, and I need to have a detailed list of what is available (as package).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module%3AFindALSA) is a complete guide for it.